# Change css variables while runtime in from nuxt

Tags: css, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I was handed a project, where they use Nuxt and in the config it says:

```js
css: ['@/assets/variables.scss'],
[...]
vuetify: {
 customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
 theme: {
  dark: false,
  themes: {
   light: {
    primary: '#FF11FF',
    secondary: '#00FF22',
},},},},
```

In the variables file are color variables, and I am supposed to change them based on a fetch result and also change the colors set in the Theme
How do I access and change those variables while the frontend is running to change the colors on runtime?

Comment: When are you doing the fetch exactly? When the project is built? Before the render? At some time during the client side navigation? The idea would probably be to override the variables created by Vuetify in the global scope (probably using CSS variables).

Comment: Yep the goal is for the user to choose the colors as customization, I also figured the best option would be to create global CSS vars @kissu